# Multiple Selection in Datagrip (Running a CTE that's not in your nested query)

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, datagrip

I'm looking for a way to run a nested correlated query that requires a CTE created above the script. For example if I had:

```
with first_cte as (
  select * 
  from a_table 
  where 1=1
)

select * from 
  (select 
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3
  from b_table b
    inner join first_cte f on f.user_id = b.user_id
    where 1=1) x
```

If I just wanted to test the nested query, it will say that first_cte doesn't exist. Is there a way to highlight the CTE so that it will run when I'm testing nested queries?

I'm using PostgreSQL btw. Thanks!!!

Comment: Convert the WITH to a temporary table? So change "WITH first_cte AS" to "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE first_cte AS ();". Remember to add the ; afterwards. Doing this will allow you to test

Comment: @MassiveOwl creating the temp tables worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are [Execute selection and Execution options features](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/executing.html) in DataGrip.

[image]